# Qual o problema ao executar Query Hibernate?

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate

Estou executando esta query no hibernate:

```
manager.createQuery("from Usuario where senha = '" + senha + "' and login = '" + login + "'", Usuario.class).getResultList();
```

Mas está dando um exception que uma das colunas não existe no BD, mas a mesma está na tabela!!!!

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'usuario0_.telefone' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
```

Comment: Eu nunca usei o Hibernate, mas olha o que ele diz na primeira linha `Unknown column 'usuario0_.telefone' in 'field list'`. Não tem algum problema com teu mapeamento? Talvez tu tenha excluído algum campo, algo assim.

Comment: Jéferson, já descobri. Na tabela o nome do campo está `tefefone`. Troquei o "t" pelo "f". Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confira a primeira linha do *stack trace*

> Unknown column 'usuario0_.telefone' in 'field list'

Isso quer dizer que o Hibernate não conseguiu encontrar a coluna `telefone`, verifique se o nome não está errado ou você não apagou este campo.

Comment: Troquei um caracter, corrigido e tudo voltou ao normal. Obrigado